# why compiler appends null character at end of each string literal C++?

Tags: c++

In C++ primer it is given that a null character is added at the end of every string literal. Why does a compiler do so?

Comment: because strings are null-terminated?

Comment: "Hello World" is defined to have that extra zero at the end - a c-language designer decided so.

Comment: That is life - bit boring

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about asking why are C-strings null-terminated.  This is more appropriate for the language designers to answer.

Comment: Besides history, some functions (like strcmp) are more efficient  not keeping track of the length of characters processed

Comment: I think its a fair question. (1) In Microsoft MASM (their assembly language environment), strings were terminated with `$`. (2) Why were they *not* NULL terminated. In either case, some good answers and citations could show up. If the question is a duplicate, then please accept my apologies.

Answer (score 5):

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null-terminated_string):

"At the time C (and the languages that it was derived from) was developed, memory was extremely limited, so using only one byte of overhead to store the length of a string was attractive. The only popular alternative at that time, usually called a "Pascal string" (though also used by early versions of BASIC), used a leading byte to store the length of the string. This allowed the string to contain NULL and made finding the length need only one memory access (O(1) (constant) time).

However, C designer Dennis Ritchie chose to follow the convention of NULL-termination, already established in BCPL *'to avoid the limitation on the length of a string caused by holding the count in an 8- or 9-bit slot, and partly because maintaining the count seemed, in our experience, less convenient than using a terminator'*..."

Answer (score 1):

It is the best way to find end of the string from a chunk of memory!
And the whole string library functions believe strings are null terminated ;)

Answer (score 0):

Because C strings are [null-terminated](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null-terminated_string).